# How would you encourage an orthogonal matrix to be a permutation matrix?

Tags: matrices, optimization, permutations, orthogonal-matrices, permutation-matrices

We want to solve an optimization problem over the space of permutation matrices (square binary matrices with exactly one entry of $1$ in each row and each column and $0$s elsewhere) with size $n \times n$, and we relax the constraint so that we operate optimization for orthogonal matrices ($P^TP=PP^T=I$), how would you encourage the matrices to be permutation matrices?

I have tried to add regularization on $\sum_{i,j} P_{ij}^4$. Would you recommend something else?

Comment: You can formulate it as an integer linear program.  If each row/column sums to 1 and each entry is in the interval $[0,1]$, and all entries are integers, then it is a permutation matrix.

Comment: "how would you encourage the matrices to be permutation matrices?" Talk to them in private. Never scream at an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: An orthogonal matrix whose entries are all $\ge 0$ is a permutation matrix.

Comment: @JairTaylor Thank you for your comment! In the case you mentioned, we are approximating permutation matrices by doubly stochastic matrices. But I want to try the alternative from the direction of orthogonal matrices.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks for your comment! Do you mean adding a penalty on negative entries?

Comment: That would do it.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2339976/339790)

Comment: If you have 1 minute, you might want to [hear](https://youtu.be/DPLSnLGE6-0?t=1185) Alexandre d'Aspremont about his "tricks".

Comment: Thanks! @RodrigodeAzevedo