# The permutation matrices are the doubly stochastic matrices with the highest Frobenius norm

Tags: matrices, reference-request, permutation-matrices, stochastic-matrices, birkhoff-polytopes

In a 2013 [talk](https://simons.berkeley.edu/talks/convex-relaxations-permutation-problems), [Alexandre d'Aspremont](https://www.di.ens.fr/%7Easpremon) did [claim](https://youtu.be/DPLSnLGE6-0?t=1215) the following:

> Among all doubly stochastic matrices, the rotations, hence, the permutation matrices, have the highest Frobenius norm

I had never encountered this result.  Searching for it on Mathematics SE produced nothing of interest.  Assuming this result is indeed correct, a reference would be most appreciated.

---

<sub>**Related:**</sub>

- [How would you encourage an orthogonal matrix to be a permutation matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4340278/339790)
- [Which probability mass function has the largest Euclidean norm?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4697871/339790)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $D$ be a doubly stochastic matrix.

**proof 1:**
Provided you understand Birkhoff - von Neumann, this is an elementary convexity result.

Consider that $\big\Vert \text{_}\big\Vert_F:M^{n\times n}\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ is a **strictly convex** map  [this follows from triangle inequality and homogeneity of re-scaling by positive numbers].  By Birkhoff- von Neumann we know $D$ is in the convex hull of $n\times n$ Permutation matrices so the extremum exists and must be at a vertex of the simplex.  That is with $w_k\geq 0$ and  $\sum_ k w_k =1$
$\big \Vert D \big \Vert_F = \big \Vert \sum_{k}w_k P^{(k)} \big \Vert_F \leq \sum_{k} w_k\cdot \big \Vert  P^{(k)} \big \Vert_F = \sum_{k} w_k\cdot\sqrt{n}=\sqrt n$
where the upper bound is Jensen's Inequality (or triangle inequality if you prefer)

**proof 2:**
observe that $0\leq d_{i,j}\leq 1$ so
$\big \Vert D\big\Vert_F^2 =\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n d_{i,j}^2\leq \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n d_{i,j}=\mathbf 1^T\big(D\mathbf 1\big)=\mathbf 1^T\mathbf 1=n$
with equality *iff* all $d_{i,j}\in \big\{0,1\big\}$ and by double stochasticity this implies exactly one $1$ in each column and row, and all else are zero, i.e. the max occurs *iff* $D$ is a permutation matrix.

Comment: Once you have that the norm is strictly convex you know it max is at some vertex, and since you can act by permutations without changing norms or anything, the norm has the same value at all vertices.