# Characterisation of permutation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, permutations, permutation-matrices

$\newcommand\mat{\mathbf}$A permutation matrix is a matrix whose columns are a permutation of the columns of the identity matrix $\mat I$. In other words, a permutation matrix is a matrix $\mat P$ with precisely one $1$ per row/column and zeros everywhere else.

A few easy observations about permutation matrices are:

- $\mat P^{-1} = \mat P^\mathsf{T}$ (orthogonality)
- $\mat P\mat 1 = \mat P^\mathsf{T}\mat1= \mat 1$ (doubly stochastic), where $\mat 1 = (1,\dots,1)$ is the all-ones vector
- Eigenvalues are $e^{2i\pi k/n}$ for $k=1,\dots,n$, where $n$ is the least positive integer such that $\mat P^n = \mat I$.

But I don't think these three properties suffice to characterise permutation matrices, and the latter two aren't too nice to work with anyway. Is there a nice set of equations one can work with which completely capture the behaviour of permutation matrices?

Comment: Along the lines of [Birkhoff's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix#Birkhoff_polytope_and_Birkhoff%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem), you could say that the permutation matrices are the [extreme points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_point) of the set of doubly-stochastic matrices.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes I've read about that theorem in pursuit of a characterisation, but how can I encapsulate what it says in the form of an equation? In a geometric sense, I believe one can see the set of doubly stochastic matrices as the convex hull of the polytope made up of the set of permutation matrices.

Comment: Your geometric characterization is correct.  Not quite sure how to describe them "in the form of an equation", as you'd like to

Comment: Mostly because I would like to prove some properties about the adjacency matrices of graphs, and I need to work with permutation matrices.

Comment: Could you be more specific?  What do the adjacency matrices look like (or what do you know about the graphs), and what kinds of properties are you trying to prove?

Comment: Relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322514/nonnegative-orthogonal-matrices

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a sufficiently nice characterisation of permutation matrices:

> Permutation matrices are the only non-negative orthogonal matrices.

*Proof*: That permutation matrices are non-negative and orthogonal is clear.

Conversely, let $\mathbf P$ be a non-negative matrix with $\mathbf P^{\mathsf T}\mathbf P=\mathbf I$. Each row and column of $\mathbf P$ must contain at least one non-zero entry, otherwise $\mathbf P^{\mathsf T}\mathbf P \neq \mathbf I$ since the product will have a column of zeros.

Now suppose two entries of $\mathbf P$ in the $i$th row are non-zero, say $p_{ij}$ and $p_{ij'}$ where $j\neq j'$. But then the entry in the $jj'$th position in $\mathbf P^{\mathsf T}\mathbf P$ will not be zero, a contradiction. A similar argument yields the corresponding fact for columns.

Finally, suppose one of the non-zero entries of $\mathbf P$ is not equal to $1$, say in the $ij$th position. Then the entry in the $jj$th position of $\mathbf P^{\mathsf T}\mathbf P$ is $\sum_{k=1}^n p_{kj}^2 =  p_{ij}^2 \neq 1$, a contradiction.

Comment: Could it be that your $PP^T$ should all be $P^TP$'s?

Comment: @darijgrinberg You're right, let me change them.

Comment: One more little tweak: You only showed that each column of $\mathbf P$ has a non-zero entry. The same for rows would require $\mathbf P \mathbf{P}^T = \mathbf{I}$.

Comment: Also correct, but I think I wrote row/column of zeros with the identity matrix in mind.